# How can I UPDATE or OVERWRITE the value of a preference in libGdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm new to android development and I'm stuck on a part where I want the value of my high-score variable to be overwritten on my preference if the user surpasses the all-time high score.
It's like a preference which will store the all-time high score of the user and will be updated if the user surpasses that particular high score.

What I did is:

1. Initially assigned a value of 0 to my preference variable named HighScore and then commented it so initially, it will get 0.
   `//preferences.putInteger("HighScore",0);`
2. Then I want to update the preference based on this condition where highScore variable is initialized to 0 on each run of the game and as the user plays the current score is allotted to the highScore variable.

`if(preferences.getInteger("HighScore")<highScore){preferences.putInteger("HighScore",highScore)}`

3. When I log the value even after the condition is true still the preference's value does not update.

Comment: The preferences get loaded into some kind of hash map that is read or written to when you use the getInteger/putInteger functions. If you want to actually commit the changes to file though, you need to use the flush function  - preferences.flush(); - If this is not the problem you're having, post some code so we can see what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step one obviously won't work in an actual game. Might as well do it properly from the beginning. When you get a preference value, you can also pass what the default value should be if it doesn't exist yet. So, you can do this exactly the same way every time the game loads, including the first time:

```
int highScore = preferences.getInteger("HighScore", 0);
```

After putting a value in the preferences, you have to call `flush()` for it to actually save it to disk.

```
if (preferences.getInteger("HighScore", 0) < highScore) { 
    preferences.putInteger("HighScore", highScore);
    preferences.flush();
}
```

Comment: The main point to note is that we need to use the flush() method every time we assign or update value to a preference.